# How can I submit this form that is inside a JSP page to a servlet?

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am pretty new in **JSP** page development and I have the following doubt about how to solve this task.

I have a **JSP page** that contains a **JQuery accordion menu**, something like it:

[image]

And this is the code that renders this accordion menu:

```
    <div id="accordion">

        <%
            for (SalDettaglio salDettaglio : (SalDettaglio[]) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("salDettaglio")) {
        %>
                <h2>
                    <!-- <span>SALDETTAGLIO: </span> -->  <%-- out.println(salDettaglio.getCodice()); --%>
                    <!--
                    <table class="salDettaglio" border="1" width="100%">

                        <tr class="salDettaglioRow">
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getStato()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getDataCreazione()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getDataRegistrazione()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreCreazione()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreConvalida()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreAcquisizione()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getFornitore()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getRmConRiserva()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%"><%=salDettaglio.getErrore()%></td>
                            <td width = "8.3%">
                                <button class="acceptButton">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
                                <button class="cancelButton">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
                                <button class="sapButton">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    -->
                    <table class="standard-table-cls" border="1" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr class="salDettaglioRow">
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getStato()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getDataCreazione()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getDataRegistrazione()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreCreazione()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreConvalida()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreAcquisizione()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getFornitore()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getRmConRiserva()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%"><%=salDettaglio.getErrore()%></th>
                                <th width = "8.33%">
                                    <button class="acceptButton">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
                                    <button class="cancelButton">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
                                    <button class="sapButton">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </h2>

                <div>
                    <table border="1" align="right" class="standard-table-cls">
                        <caption><div align="center"><b>RM</b></div></caption>

                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th width="14.2%">Codice RM</th>
                                <th width="14.2%">Autore Firma</th>
                                <th width="14.2%">Data Firma</th>
                                <th width="14.2%">Acq Riserva</th>
                                <th width="14.2%">Consegna Finale</th>
                                <th width="14.2%">Descrizione RM</th>
                                <th width="14.2%">Imponibile</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <%
                        for (RM currentRM : salDettaglio.getRM()) {
                            String test = currentRM.getAcqRiserva();
                        %>

                                <tr id="rmRow">
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getCodiceRm()%></td>
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getAutoreFirma()%></td>
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getDataFirma()%></td>
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getAcqRiserva()%></td>
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getConsegnaFinale()%></td>
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getDescrizioneRM()%></td>
                                    <td><%=currentRM.getImponibile().toString()%></td>
                                </tr>

                    <%}%>
                    </table>
                </div>
        <%
            }
        %>

   </div>
```

As you can see in the previous immage in the **last column** of the table putted inside the **accordion header** there are 3 **icons** that are implemented using **JQuery buttons**, these:

```
<th width = "8.33%">
    <button class="acceptButton">ACCEPT ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button class="cancelButton">CANCEL ICON BUTTON</button>
    <button class="sapButton">SAP ICON BUTTON</button>
</th>
```

Now what I have to do is submit a value (at this time even a fixed value, for esample: 1 for the first button, 2 for the second button and 3 for the third button) to the servlet that handle this view when a button is clicked.

I think that I have to use a form that submit it in post. But what exactly have I to do? Searching online I founded this article: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_form_processing.htm

But in the previous tutorial show how to submit a form **from an HTML page to a JSP** but this is not what I want to do.

How can I submit a form into a JSP to a servlet?

Tnx

Comment: Why not a jquery onclick event on the buttons and then a jquery.ajax jquery.post to the servlet? It's the browser the one that makes the HTTP post request eventually to the server whether it is PHP, JSP or Servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jquery `$.post` [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request to achive this:

```
<table>
   <td><input type="text" value="test" id="name" />
   <td><button onclick="post(<%=entity.id%>)">submit</button><td>
</table>

<script>
  function post(id){
     var name=$("#name").val();

     $.post(
        "/myservlet", { customerid: id, customername: name }
     ).done(function(data){
        alert(data);
       //This will send get request to your servlet. can use this if your previous
       //post request done any update in DB
       window.location.href='/myservlet?customerid='+id;
     });
  }
</script>
```